# How to configure multiple login methods for Azure B2C in react

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication

I am using React to build a login for my web app.
I currently have a login that handles login this way:

[image]

I am new to Azure and I don't know how to have the multiple login options like this site does.

[image]

Is this an Azure setting or something I need to add to my config file?
Is there a name for each sign in method I can investigate because without knowing the terms I find it hard to find any tutorial on getting both sign in methods to show.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional sign in options like external AD,or social accounts like Google, Twitter, Facebook. Those are called `identity provider`s [aka `IdP`], any ID provider that supports `OAuth or` `OIDC` can be registered with your Azure B2C directory to support this login methods. You can create your own 'user flows' in `B2C` supporting this, when you want to do anything custom you can author 'custom policies' using XML. Refer the MS doc on [userflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview#user-flows), [sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/sign-in-options) options.